# Reliably testing cross-platform terminal/console output

Tags: python, testing, cross-platform, virtual-machine, image-recognition

Are there any frameworks that let me reliably test the output of the terminal/console?

The problem is that if I redirect the stdout, its encoding, mode and probably other settings and capabilities are lost. The only way I see it is to do output to actual console/terminal and compare it graphically. Is there anything that could help with this task across platforms?

I am using Python and [my module](https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/python-wget/) needs to be run on Windows, Linux, BSD, OS X and be able to output unicode characters to stdout without failing with various unicode decode errors.

Comment: For image-recognition, [sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) may could be used.

Comment: @Rainman yes, this is what I am thinking about, but running Sikuli for test matrix consisting from Linux, OS X, Windows and Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.4, 3.5 and PyPy is still a big problem.

Comment: sikuli support java. I am trying to implement a sikuli library which could be used by Robot Framework. The server part is implemented with java, and could be called through xml rpc. That mean the client could be implemented with different program language, and server part could be deployed to different OS. I am not sure whether this solution could satisfy for you. [robotframework-SikuliLibrary](https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/). Note only windows sikuli api jar is included, but could be replaced.